# BCryptPasswordEncoder Spring Security - is it possible to set count of log rounds (strength) in application properties?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I can do it like this:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
}
```

But I want to be able to change this value in the `application.properties`. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to have the strength in the application.properties like this

```
password.encoder.strength=12
```

and then injecting the value to the configuration class

```
@Value("${password.encoder.strength}")
private int strength;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(strength);
}
```